# Need to Make Parent-Child Menu with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen lots of examples of this using static values but I have been unable to find an example that is like my situation.  My data is coming back like this:

```
    data = [
        {
            MenuId = 1,
            MenuName = "Contractor Management",
        OrderId = 1,
        ParentId = 0


        },
        {
            MenuId = 2,
            MenuName = "Some Other Management",
        OrderId = 1,
        ParentId = 1


        },
{
            MenuId = 3,
            MenuName = "Some Menu Name",
        OrderId = 2,
        ParentId = 0


        },
{
            MenuId = 4,
            MenuName = "Another Menu Name",
        OrderId = 2,
        ParentId = 3


        },
{
            MenuId = 5,
            MenuName = "Blah Management",
        OrderId = 2,
        ParentId = 3


        },

    ];
```

I have read that the best way to display the hierarchy using ng-repeat is to have it in this order:

```
Parent = [{MenuId:1, MenuName:Contractors, ParentId=0, OrderId =1, Children=[{MenuId:2, MenuName: blahblah, ParentId = 1, OrderId = 1}, etc.]
```

I am able to isolate the parent and the children when I get the data because the Parents all have a parentId = 0, but I can't figure out how to get the children into each parent.  I tried the following but of course, it is not working:

```
 getmenuItems();
function getmenuItems() {
    debugger;
    generalsearchService.getMenuItems()
     .success(function (data) {
         //$scope.menuItems = data;
         $scope.parents = [];
         $scope.children = [];
         $scope.parents[0].children = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
         {
             if(data[i].ParentId == 0)
             {
                 $scope.parents.push(data[i]);

             }
             else {
                 $scope.children.push(data[i]);
             }
         }
         for (var i = 0; i < $scope.parents.length; i++)
         {
             for(var x = 0; x <$scope.children.length; x++)
             {
                 if($scope.children[x].ParentId = $scope.parents[i].WebMenuId)
                 {
                     $scope.parents[i].children.push($scope.children[x]);
                 }
             }
         }

         return $scope.parents;
     });
};
```

and this in my HTML:

```
  <ul>
        <li ng-repeat-start="parent in parents" class="header">{{parent.MenuName}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="child in parents.children" class="item">{{child.MenuName}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat-end><br /></li>
    </ul>
```

The first part of the javascript works fine for isolating the parents and the children, but the second part errors out.  Can someone please help me?  I am new to Angular and Javascript but I need to get this working for a project that is due on Tuesday.  ANY assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're making the array `$scope.parents`, but then treating it as an object by assigning an array as a property `$scope.parents.children`. You probably want to assign the children to the actual parent item such as `$scope.parents[0].children = []`. Also what's `$scope.getchildren`? You don't declare it anywhere.

Comment: $scope.getchildren was something I was trying  because I had $scope.children = [] and I thought it was getting it confused with $scope.parents.children.  I just forgot to change it back to $scope.children before I posted the code.  Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused you have `$scope.parents.children` and `$scope.children` is that on purpose?

Comment: I was using $scope.children to "separate" the children from success(data).  $scope.parents.children was my attempt to add the appropriate children to each parent.  So yes, it was on purpose.

Comment: I tried using $scope.parents[0].children = [] to add the children, but it is still not working.

Comment: No sorry I didn't mean to write it like how you just updated it. I meant that if `$scope.parents` is an array (which it is), then you probably want to assign child arrays to the items in the array, not the array itself. Sorry but I think there are number of issues you're facing here.

Comment: If you make a fiddle of your problem, it'll be easier to help you without just writing a solution for you.

Comment: The data you've shown at the top is not JSON. Please format it so we can help you.

Comment: I don't know how to make a fiddle.

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle, but I don't really know what's needed for this to work properly.  My data comes back from a call to our database through an MVC controller.  Th fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/JustRani/1m0L7gqs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this plunkr with a solution for your problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4XddPGvfjqkbo3VIM3QA?p=preview

The idea is to create one single json object that will contain several levels of objects: level one would be the parent, level two the list of children. This can be done by iterating first through your list and creating the json with only parent levels, then iterate again to match the children with their parents:

```
    $scope.menu = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
      if (value.ParentId == 0){
        $scope.menu.push(value);
       } 
     });

   angular.forEach( data, function(value, key) {
    if (value.ParentId != 0){
       angular.forEach($scope.menu, function(value2, key2) {
        if (value.ParentId == value2.MenuId){
          if(value2.children == undefined){
            value2.children = [];
            value2.showChildren = false;
          } 
          value2.children.push(value);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

And the html would be:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="parent in menu" class="header">{{parent.MenuName}}<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="child in parent.children" class="item">{{child.MenuName}}</li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OMG!  Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I would never have figured that out on my own!